# Passing variable through response object in Flask framework

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask

I need to pass a variable along with response object while complete signup process and display the success message on the same page. I tried so many ways but I couldn't find any idea how to do that. Please look at this scenario and help me out.

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def signup():
        message = ''
        email = ''
        password = ''
        resp = app.make_response(render_template('signup.html'))
        if request.method == 'POST':
            import datetime
            email = request.form['emailInput']
            password = request.form['pswdInput']

            if len(password) < 3:
                message = Markup("<p style='color:red;'> Password Length Should Be More Than 3 Character </p> ")
                return render_template('signup.html', message = message)

            expire_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            expire_date = expire_date + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
            resp.set_cookie('userEmail', email, expires=expire_date)
            resp.set_cookie('userPassword', password, expires=expire_date)

            message = Markup("<h1> Registration successfull! </h1>")
            resp.headers.set('message', message)
            return resp

        return render_template('signup.html', message = message)
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
<a href = "{{url_for('home')}}"> Home </a>
    <form id="signup" method="POST" action="{{url_for('signup')}}">

        <div class="header">

            <h3>Sign Up</h3>

            <p>You want to fill out this form</p>

        </div>

        <div class="sep"></div>

        <div class="">

            <input type="email" name="emailInput" placeholder="e-mail" autofocus />

            <input type="password" name="pswdInput" placeholder="Password" />

            <div class="">
                <input name="joinCheck" name="joinCheck" value="1" type="checkbox" /><label class="terms">I accept the terms of use</label>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">SIGN UP FOR INVITE NOW</a>

        </div>
        <div>
            {{message}}
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: How is your `message` keyword reflected in your HTML? Please paste that snippet as well. Your `message` variable should be declared as `None` not an empty string

Comment: 3mangoHero1, Please check HTML code where I use message variable to display string.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with this little part: what does `app.make_response()` do? Inside of the `render_template()` in that line, it's being called without the `message` keyword as you did in the GET section of your code

Comment: make_response is converted the return value from a view function to a real response object that is an instance of response_class.

In render_template(), you can pass HTML and also dynamic variables which will be displayed after rendered. HTML in the script was replaced by render_template('<filename>.html').

Answer (score 1):

> `resp = app.make_response(render_template('signup.html'))`

This is missing your `message` keyword. Change it to:

```
resp = app.make_response(render_template('signup.html', message=message))
```

You need to move this code down also, because to it, it sees the `message` variable directly above as the empty string and assigns that to its keyword. I would place it right above your `resp.set_cookie()` code.

Finally, move this:

> `message = Markup("<h1> Registration successfull! </h1>")`

Above the `app.make_response()` code you just moved. Your `message` variable needs to be set before the response code is initialized.

*Just a small tip*: I would change `message = " "` to `message = None`. Otherwise, in the compiled HTML, it just looks like there's an empty `div`. This won't be too detrimental in this small case, but I'd definitely make it a rule of thumb in future, larger projects. Then, in your HTML:

```
{% if message %}
    <div>
        {{message}}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Cheers.

Comment: If I take message variable on above of resp then always this message will appeared even if problem occurred in set_cookies() method and also if need to display proper message then how can I overwrite message variable.

Comment: @cSharma If you initialize your `message` variable to `None`, no message will be displayed. It is overwritten each time you reassign the variable to your `Markup` text

Comment: If I do like and want to display error text 
try:
                resp.set_cookie('userEmail', email, expires=expire_date)
                resp.set_cookie('userPassword', password, expires=expire_date)
        except Exception as ex:
            message = ex

Comment: I need to pass any data while return time. Did you get my point?

Comment: @cSharma What was the result of that? What kind of error are you trying to achieve?